# Dereference of a possibly null reference warning

Tags: c#, null, warnings, dereference

I have an object called `conversationService`.

When I try to call a method on the object I get a warning:

> 'conversationService' may be null here. CS8602: Dereference of a
> possibly null reference.

The thing is, I don't think it can be null there. Is there something I'm missing and how can I get rid of this warning?

This is my code:

```
public string GetNextState(string input)
{
    if (conversationService == null)
        LoadConversationService();

    List<ConversationResponse> responses = conversationService.PredictResponse(new Conversation(input));
    return responses.First().Text;
}

public void LoadConversationService()
{
    conversationService = new ConversationService();
}
```

Here is an image showing code with the warning:

[Code showing a warning of a dereference of a possibly null reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfWvs.png)

I know that I can write it as

```
conversationService!.PredictResponse();
```

but I think it introduces clutter that should not be needed.

I tried checking for a null reference and then handling it before my line of code that gets the warning. I expected it to make the compiler understand that it can not be null when the dereferencing occurs but it did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is that the conversationService was null when this class's constructor was initialized. To avoid this issue, you can directly create an instance of the conversationService object in the constructor of the class like this:

```cs
private ConversationService conversationService = new ConversationService();

public string GetNextState(string input)
{
    List<ConversationResponse> responses = conversationService.PredictResponse(new Conversation(input));
    return responses.First().Text;
}
```

This approach will prevent null warnings from occurring.

You could also wrap the conversationResponse in a Getter such as

```cs
public string GetNextState(string input)
{
    List<ConversationResponse> responses = GetConversationService().PredictResponse(new Conversation(input));
    return responses.First().Text;
}

public ConversationService GetConversationService()
{
    if(conversationService == null) conversationService = new ConversationService();
    return conversationService();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the null forgiving operator (!) to suppress these warnings, as you were doing previously.

Comment: I didn't show the real code in my question. In reality LoadConversationService() is not just making a new object, it is more complicated than that which is why I don't want to call it from the constructor. I want it to be lazily loaded.

Thank you for the suggestion of the null forgiving operator but I was wondering if there is any way of avoiding that since the way I see it it should not be needed here. I don't think there is any way conversationService can be null when PredictResponse(), I think the compiler should understand that but I guess it doesn't? Maybe I'm just missing something?

Comment: I would suggest if the ConversatioinService object is very complicated or is bad performance wise, you should probabbly refactor that instead. The other way would be like I said, to make a wrapper called GetConversaionService which loads (if null) and returns the conversaion service

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access method from the nullable object, so the compiler warns you that **conversationService** may be null. You can write `conversationService?.PredictResponse(...)` to tell the compiler that you are expecting possible **null**.

Comment: But when PredictResponse() is called conversationService can not be null? Is this just the current state of the compiler, that it doesn't understand that and I have to manually tell it that it can't be null?